# Thoughts on Mathematics of Statistics by Kenney?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references

This book is written in 1939. It's available here on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/MathematicsOfStatisticsPartI).

Would you recommend this as an introduction to the mathematics of statistics for beginners?

Comment: Books that old tend to be hard to read and to miss a comprehensive view of the field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good resources (online or book) on the mathematical foundations of statistics](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56385/good-resources-online-or-book-on-the-mathematical-foundations-of-statistics)

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't. The word **"likelihood"** appears only two times in the whole book (both volumes). Also, the anti-Bayesian criticisms are definitely dated. As my first book, I would use [DeGroot-Schervish](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321500466).

Answer (score 3):

What's your background? [Casella & Berger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534243126) is by far my favourite book on mathematical statistics (there's a very cheap international edition). There's [Hogg Craig](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321795431) too, which you can use as second source since it's got a similar scope.

Comment: Thanks. I never actually did a course in statistics and I thought it started off well. My b/g is mechanical engineering.

Comment: @Kedar Mhaswade given that you've got a solid mathematical background, Casella & Berger is the way to go. It's the book that will make you passionate for stats.

Answer (score 2):

If you want books on mathematical statistics at a graduate level, try

- [Essentials Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461448174) by Boos and Stefanski
- [Statistical Theory: a concise introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439851840) by Abramovich and Ritov
- [Understanding Advanced Statistical Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439851840) by Westfall and Henning
- [Probability for Statistics and Machine Learning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/146142884X) by Das Gupta
- [All of Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387402721) by Wasserman

Answer (score 1):

If you like old books, then I'd recommend Feller's classic [text](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471257087). It has all the math you need, and explains all very clearly.

Comment: It has all the math needed to read it?

Comment: @Khashaa, yes, and it doesn't have math that you don't need :) It's full of examples, which will help you develop the intuition.

Comment: @Aksakal: Feller is not about statistics but probability theory...

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a free online introductory statistics textbook, may I recommend to have a look at [OpenIntro Statistics](https://www.openintro.org/)? Not only it's well-written and quite easy to understand, but it also has nice online interactive exercises in R available at [datacamp.org](http://datacamp.com/)