# I want to get a Ph.D. in statistics. What books should I read after Elementary Statistics?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references

It has been some time since I've been in a statistics course. I actually have a degree in statistics but it has been some time, so I can't recall the upper level stats. I know Elementary Statistics and Statistical Methods but as for theoretical stats I would need some help. As for proofs in stats, would I need to read, intro to proofs, analysis and linear algebra books before proceeding into reading higher level stats. I would really appreciate feedback, I would love to contribute to the mathematics world and I really enjoy statistics.

Comment: @Tavrock. I definitely disagree. This is a prolific question as there are many statisticians (including me) who would love to do a phd in stats, but have lack of pre-knowledge in some areas. http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4576/are-very-elementary-questions-off-topic-on-crossvalidated?cb=1

Comment: Testing Statistical Hypotheses

Comment: A Ph.D. typically requires some years in graduate school, completing coursework and writing a thesis under supervision containing publishable work. The details depend on country, so saying where you are based would focus advice.

Comment: I am not clear that the mention of ambition towards a Ph.D. makes this precise enough. It seems too close to what books should I read after introductory texts and is thus very open-ended. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: See [Advanced statistics books recommendation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/33197/17230), [What to learn after Casella & Berger?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/91863/17230), & [Good resources (online or book) on the mathematical foundations of statistics](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56385/17230), from which in my opinion this q. isn't clearly distinguished. These answers are also worth reading: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7477/17230 & http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25725/17230.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am from Texas and I already have a masters in mathematics and I have written a thesis as well. My thesis advisor advised me to publish it but I did not do so after all. In my thesis I used various statistical methods to create a comparative study .

Comment: I guess my question(s) are what books should I read to increase my chances into getting ready for phd school. I know higher level statistics involves a lot of Linear Algebra which I have not seen in years. Should I start reading advanced statistic books (anything right after elementary statistics)  or read up on analysis and linear algebra. I appreciated you're input, I am new to this site so sorry if I made any mistakes on asking my question.